# iOS, ObjC: Service running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, uilocalnotification

I've been building a streaming app and there I have to implement a system which must start at midnight and terminate at morning. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to implement it.

This system must stay on watch at the application start and continue running even when application went background.

Meanwhile, I tried to implement a timer and it runs only for a while and after some times dies. My application is not a VoiP or StandApp. Officially I have no rights to run an infinite service. Anyway I need a solution that will call a method at 12 am and it start file download.

```
//and create new timer with async call:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //run function methodRunAfterBackground
    NSTimer* t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(isNightFrame) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
});
```

Then I tried to play with `UILocalnotifications` but it seems there must be user iteration. He must tap on notification.

I need some advise which way to go and how to get the things just right. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a non-jailbroken device, there is no way to achieve what you want to do.
If your app is not using any of the background modes offered by Apple, you won't be able to trigger any code execution after the app is suspended by iOS.
I guess that you use the "App plays audio" background mode. Even with this mode enabled, the app will be suspended if your app is not actually playing audio.

**TL;DR:** There is **no way** to resume a suspended app **without the user's interaction** on a non-jailbroken device.

**EDIT:** Actually, it may be possible to execute some code by using `Background Fetch`, but I'm pretty sure that iOS will never let you start an audio session from `background fetch` for an app that has been suspended.

**EDIT 2:** According to [this article](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-background-fetch-ios), you can't choose to trigger a `Background Fetch`. iOS decides to trigger it for your app.

> How frequent your application can perform a background fetch is
>   determined by the system. It depends on factors such as:
>
> Whether network connectivity is available at that particular time
>   Whether the device is awake
>   How much data and time your application
>   has taken in its previous attempt to perform a background fetch
>   In
>   other words, your application is entirely at the mercy of the system
>   to schedule background fetch for you.
>   In addition, each time your
>   application uses background fetch, it has at most 30 seconds to
>   complete the process.

iOS can decide to trigger a `Background Fetch` after your app received a Push/Local notification. But it's absolutely not reliable (like, at all).

Comment: Thank you for your great response. Actually, the service I need to start is file download. How can I commit a background fetch after LocalNotifcation is fired when my application is in background? Which AppDelegate method I need to implement?

Comment: For local notification, there isn't any method which call when notification fires. App will never know when local notification fired. But once you tap the notification it will accessible to app.